# Removing spacing between HTML table rows and columns

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table in which I want the elements to be connected at the borders(no spacing at all). However, there seems to be a small gap between the rows and the columns that I cannot remove.

Here is a visual of the html: https://jsfiddle.net/sy2h8t9c/
I have set the cellspacing, border-spacing, and cellpadding to 0.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><div></div></th>
    <th><div></div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><div></div></th>
    <th><div></div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><div></div></th>
    <th><div></div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, td {
  border: none;
  margin:0px;
  cellspacing:0px;
  border-spacing:0px;
  cell-padding:0px;
}
div{
  width:5px;
  height:5px;
  background-color:black;
  display:block;
}
```

The current result is provided in the jsfiddle. I am trying to make it so that it appears to be a solid black box. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> cellspacing:0px;
> ```

Remove this. There **used** to be an HTML attribute named `cellspacing`, but it was obsoleted by CSS two decades ago.

> ```
> cell-padding:0px;
> ```

The property is called `padding`. There isn't a special version of it for tables. (There used to be an HTML attribute named `cellpadding`, but again, CSS came along in the '90s and it isn't needed any more).

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

div {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div></div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div></div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div></div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding: 0;` to your code

```
table, th, td {
  border: none;
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0;
  cellspacing:0px;
  border-spacing:0px;
  cell-padding:0px;
}
```